# Can I set up an OCMock object to expect a char * argument?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, ocmock

I'm trying to verify that a method will be called on a mocked object with a particular pointer value for one of the method's arguments, but I keep getting an "Argument type '*' not supported." exception when the mocked method is called. Here's my test code:

```
uint8_t *buf = calloc(65, sizeof(uint8_t));
id stream = [OCMockObject niceMockForClass:[NSInputStream class]];
[[stream expect] read:buf maxLength:64];
id myStream = [[MyStream alloc] initWithStream:stream];
// myStream should pass read:maxLength: call through to stream
[myStream read:buf maxLength:64];
STAssertNoThrow([stream verify], @"Did not pass call through");
```

Here's `-[MyStream read:maxLength:]`:

```
- (NSInteger)read:(uint8_t *)buffer maxLength:maxLength {
    // internalStream is the stream passed to -initWithStream:
    return [self.internalStream read:buffer maxLength:maxLength];
}
```

When I call -read:maxLength: on the mocked stream, I get the "Argument type '*' not supported." exception. Is it possible to expect a call with a specific pointer argument value?

EDIT:

Looks like this issue may be specific to char * (or uint8_t *) arguments. Objective C @encodes them as '*' and OCMock's type handling code only treats '^'-encoded values as pointers. I've tried hacking `+[OCMArg resolveSpecialValues:]` and `-[NSInvocation getArgumentAtIndexAsObject:]` (in NSInvocation+OCMAdditions.m) to treat '*' the same as '^'. This has stopped the exception, but my expectation is still not met.

Does anybody know how else to handle this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround for this issue. Trying to fix OCMock to handle '*'-encoded types was a rabbit hole full of hurt, but I was able to get my tests working by creating a category on NSInputStream that made it return a method signature OCMock is able to work with:

```
@interface NSInputStream (OCMockFix)
  + (NSMethodSignature *)instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)selector;
  - (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)selector;
@end

@implementation NSInputStream (OCMockFix)
  + (NSMethodSignature *)instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)selector {
    if (sel_isEqual(selector, @selector(read:maxLength:))) {
      // Original signature is "i@:*I". Change '*' to '^C'
      return [NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:"i@:^CI"];
    } else {
      return [super instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:selector];
    }
  }
  - (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)selector {
    return [[self class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:selector];
  }
@end
```